# JavaScript desktop notification does not work on the server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification

I have deployed my javascript desktop notification code on the web server but it is not working. It's working on my localhost properly. Can somebody help me out?

JavaScript Snippet

```
function showNotifaication() {
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        alert("Desktop notifications is not supported by this browser. Try another.");
        return;
    } else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        var myNotification = new Notification("Twitter", {
            icon: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/875087697177567232/Qfy0kRIP_400x400.jpg",
            body: "Follow me on Twitter."
        });
        myNotification.onclick = function () {
            window.open("https://twitter.com/google");
        };

    } else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission(function (userPermission) {
            if (userPermission === "granted") {
                var myNotification = new Notification("Google", {
                    icon: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/839721704163155970/LI_TRk1z_400x400.jpg",
                    body: "Search on the Web."
                });
                myNotification.onclick = function () {
                    window.open("http://www.google.com");
                };

            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the button code

```
<button onclick="showNotifaication();">Show Notification</button>
```

All the above code works fine for the local machine whenever I have deployed it on the Apache server it will not work. One thing that I have noticed that my browser has already blocked the Notification and it is disabled also. No option for enables it.

[image: Screen shot of Chrome browser]

Comment: Is your application running through HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: It is running through HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

From MDN, it looks like starting from [Chrome 62](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification#Browser_compatibility), notificatin API is available in [secure contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts) only, i.e. only through localhost or a website running on HTTPS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript desktop notification only works with HTTPS connection.